# How to add a property to a control's DataBindings

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress, custom-controls

I want to write a control derived from CheckedListBoxControl (DevExpress), and I need to add a property to the `(DataBindings)`

These are the standard Properties shown in the PropertyGrid:

[image]

So I can only choose between `Tag` and `Text`.
**What I want is to add a third option called `gttMasterField`** (which will be of type `int`, don't know if this matters)

I have been experimenting with the documentation but with no results.
These don't seem to cover exact what I am looking for, I don't know the correct search terms to find this, which makes it difficult to google for it. It will probably be somewhere in the documentation but also there I don't know on what terms to look for.

[Create a Windows Forms user control that supports simple data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-simple-data-binding?view=vs-2022)
[Create a Windows Forms user control that supports lookup data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-lookup-data-binding?view=vs-2022)
[Create a Windows Forms user control that supports complex data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-windows-forms-user-control-that-supports-complex-data-binding?view=vs-2022)

Here is some code with comments that will also help to explain what I am searching for

```
public partial class gttDXManyToManyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBoxControl
{
    private int _gttMasterField;
  
    // This I want populated by setting the binding property MasterField
    public int gttMasterField
    {
        get { return _gttMasterField; }
        set { _gttMasterField = value; }
    }
}
```

The project is a `dotnet framework 4.7.2`

Comment: It looks like you have a .Net 5+ Project there: [WinForms: .NET 5 Design Time Enhancements](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/ctodx/archive/2021/07/01/winforms-net-5-design-time-enhancements.aspx)

Comment: @Jimi No it's a dotnet framework 4.7.2 project

Comment: Do you mean you just want to add the `gttMasterField` Property to the `(DataBindings)` list? In that case, it's just a matter of decorating the Property with `[Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`

Comment: @Jimi Yes, that is exact what I mean. Thank you. I will accept this if you write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a custom Property appear in the PropertyGrid's (DataBindings), decorate the Property with the [BindableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute) set to `true`:

```
[Bindable(true)]
public int gttMasterField
{
    get { return _gttMasterField; }
    set { _gttMasterField = value; }
}
```

Optionally also decorate with the desired [DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultbindingpropertyattribute) attribute

```
[Bindable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public int gttMasterField
{
    get { return _gttMasterField; }
    set { _gttMasterField = value; }
}
```

The class can also specify the default bindable Property, settings a [DefaultBindingPropertyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultbindingpropertyattribute):

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("gttMasterField")]
public partial class gttDXManyToManyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBoxControl
{
    private int _gttMasterField;

    [Bindable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public int gttMasterField
    {
        get { return _gttMasterField; }
        set { _gttMasterField = value; }
    }
}
```

---

Important note:
the class should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) -> a bindable Property is supposed to raise notification events. When the binding is set in the Designer, a BindingSource is generated to mediate the binding, but it requires that the objects involved send change notifications (mostrly to determine when the Property value is updated, usually as `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`).

For example:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[DefaultBindingProperty("gttMasterField")]
public partial class gttDXManyToManyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBoxControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int _gttMasterField;

    [Bindable(true)]
    public int gttMasterField
    {
        get { return _gttMasterField; }
        set { _gttMasterField = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

---

Setting `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` implies initialization. If a BindingSource is used, this object supports initialization on itself, the Attribute is not strictly required.
It could be set to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden`, though, depending on the use case.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not knew about the NotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Glad it helped :) -- Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your UserControl is not *strictly* required, since the bound value is updated on validation. But in two-way binding, you may expect to see a value change immediately in the data source.